# the condition that changes the directory

Tags: c#

goal: we are not talking about files, but about folders. if the desired folder, which is specified in the array of strings, is available on the desktop, then we need to get subdirectories and paths to this folder, if the desired folder is not on the desktop, then the search for this folder has already been performed in appdata, and then the same thing, if the folder is present, then we get subdirectories and paths to this folder.

```
string[] directory = new string [] {@"folder1/", @"folder3/", }

foreach (string sPath in directory)
{
      string Path;
      
      if (sPath.Contains("folder1"))
      {
          Path = Desktop + sPath;
      }
      else
      { 
          Path = Appdata + sPath;
      }
```

there is an  `if (sPath.Contains("folder1"))`

I intended the `string Path`  to first take the `Path = "Desktop + sPath"` logic to return the names of the subdirectories of the `folder1`  folder

```
if (Directory.Exists(Path)) foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories(Path))
{
  Console.WriteLine(folder);
```

this code does not work for me = (if you delete a folder from the desktop, which, for example, was present, then the search from another place that is specified in the code is not carried out( how to fix the situation?

```
string Path;
      
if (sPath.Contains("folder1"))
{
   Path = Desktop + sPath;
}
else
{ 
   Path = Appdata + sPath;
}
```

full code

```
string [] directory = new string [] {@"folder1/", @"folder3/", }

foreach (string sPath in directory)
{
      string sFullPath;
      
      if (sPath.Contains("folder1"))
      {
          sFullPath = Desktop + sPath;
      }
      else
      { 
          sFullPath = Appdata + sPath;
      }
      
      if (Directory.Exists(sFullPath)) foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories(sFullPath))
      {
         Console.WriteLine(folder);
      }

}
```

Comment: You can't look up the folder one time. You must verify that it exists every time you want to access it.

Comment: Also in an iteration use Directory.EnumerateDirectories instead of GetDirectories. The performance is much better.

Comment: `if (sPath.Contains("folder1"))` what's the use of this line?

Comment: Unrelated: `Path = Desktop + sPath;` - better use `Path.Combine`. Fixes some quirks for you.

Comment: @bioniccode everything happens in a loop, so the file check is one

Comment: @chetan this is a directory-to-folder check(I know there is another check there, but I need to do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we should come to terms. To be "available on the desktop" is to **be a subfolder** of

```
// Have a look at 
//   Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory
//   Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory
// as well
string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

then we can manipulate with `directory` array:

```
string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData); 

string[] directory = new string [] {@"folder1/", @"folder3/", };

foreach (string sPath in directory) {
  if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(desktop, sPath))) {
    // available on the desktop
  }
  else if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(appData, sPath))) {
    // available on the AppData
  }
  else {
    // not exists
  } 
}
```